# How to get all objects of a Parent model of which foreign key exist in child model in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 models

```
#models
class Parent(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model)
     parentLink = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
     timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want all the objects of Parent model having foreign key mentioned in Child model and some filter on timeStamp field.

How do I do this reverse fetching of objects?

It's MySQL would be something like this

```
SELECT Parent.name FROM Parent JOIN Child on Parent.Id = Child.parentLink WHERE Child.timeStamp > '2016-01-01 : 00.00.00'
```

Comment: `timeStamp` is not a Prent's field.

Comment: @Gocht, Sorry for the typo.

Comment: You mean, get all parents that belongs to a child? Some parents are not on any child?

Comment: Yes, All Parents there are in child. Every parent may or may not be in child.

Comment: @T.Opletal using prefetch related he will get Childs. Like: `Child.objects.filter(timeStamp='some_value').prefetch_related('parentLink')` and then get the parent for every child.

Comment: @Gocht I deleted my comment, because I realized he doesn't need to use prefetch_related, since he doesn't need any info to retrieve from Child. However, in the example you posted, you should use `select_related`. Prefetch related have to be used from parent to child. Like this: `Parent.objects.prefetch_related('child_set')`. Also good to mention that  setting a `related_name` on Child will make it more readable and easier to navigate

Comment: @PranayjeetThakare you can always use [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Comment: Thanks @Gocht but raw queries don't return objects, I need Objects of parent model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you need correctly, it should be something like this:

```
Parent.objects.filter(
    child__isnull=False,
    child__timeStamp__gt=datetime.strptime(
        '2016-01-01 00.00.00',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S'
    )
)
```

This fetches all `Parent` objects for which there is a child whose timestamp is later than 2016/01/01.

Comment: From the docs, ["To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) I've tried it and it works (in 1.9 at least).

Comment: In your link's example `Entry` has a `Blog` field, this is not that case.

Comment: Check the following example. :)